# Networking in c#,not lan

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I wanted to learn how networking in c# works, so I learned how to use TCP server and clients.
The only problem is that it's working only if both computers are connected to the same network..

How can I make them communicate even if they aren't?

Comment: connect them both to the internet? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP/IP sockets should work between any two end points as long as there is a route between them. If there is no route  between them then you are talking about a case where there are two separate disconnected networks. In that case you will need something to bridge the two networks.

If you are using TCP/IP server/client communication and the computers are on different networks that has a route connecting them and they cannot communicate then you should look at firewall settings and other network settings to make sure TCP/IP packets from one network are able to reach the other network.

Make sure you are using the correct IP address when the client tries to connect to the server. If you have a server at IP address 10.0.0.5 listening on port 4823 try to telnet to that IP address from the client using the server IP address 10.0.0.5 and port 4823. If it connects that usually means that you have things set up right.

From a command prompt: `telnet 10.0.0.5 4823`

Comment: Exactly what I was about to write. I would bet dollars to donuts that all Tom needs to do is set up port forwarding on his server endpoint and use the public IP instead of the private IP and his program will work fine.

Comment: The other thing is to make sure that he specifies the correct external IP address.

Comment: OK, so I checked my public IP here : www.mypublicip.com .
And the client is connecting like this : 
Client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("109.64.200.92"), 8001);
(The IP is the result)
The server still doesn't recognize..

Comment: What is the server side doing in the code? You may have to set up your router to do port forwarding so that requests to port 8001 get sent to the PC your server software is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Communication in TCP is done with IP addresses. So even if the client and the server are not on the same network if you specify the IP address of the server, the client will be able to communicate with it (assuming of course the network that the client resides on is configured properly and knows how to reach the server's network). You could also use the DNS service and provide the FQDN of the server instead of an IP address. The DNS server on the client network will resolve the server's FQDN to an IP address.